# How to use conditions dynamically in WHERE clause in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

In SQL, I want to replace the multiple conditions (set of conditions are not known during compilation) with a function in WHERE clause where this function will return the set of the conditions (generated during run time).

For example, Function **FUNC_CON** returns the set of the conditions on running the query:

```
select FUNC_CON from dual;
--output is: condition1 = value1 AND condition2 = value2 AND so on..
```

Please suggest how to use **this output** in another select query.

I have already executed the following code:

```
select * from table1 where (select FUNC_CON from dual);
```

But this is giving me an error with "missing expression"

Comment: It's giving the error because it's not valid SQL - you're not telling it what to do with the results of the subquery, ie. it's missing *"an expression"*.

Comment: can you suggest an alternative to use this function in WHERE clause of an SQL?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways, how you can achieve this. First, by using dinamic SQL in stored procedure. Something like that:

```
PROCEDURE CR_VIEW IS
cond_str VARCHAR2...
BEGIN
...
SELECT FUNC_CON INTO cond_str FROM DUAL;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ... AS SELECT ... FROM ...
WHERE ' || cond_str;
...
END CR_VIEW;
```

Or just by directly implementing your function into create view statement using condition operators. For exapmle:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ... AS SELECT ... FROM ...
    WHERE ((CASE WHEN (*condition on using condition*) 
THEN (*your condition, returning 1 then true*) ELSE 1 END = 1) AND ...
```

But the second one will be much harder to maintain.

---

For exapmle, you have a table of orders:

t_orders
(order_id NUMBER,
order_name VARCHAR2,
order_sum NUMBER)

And you want to create a view, which will show you orders with sum more than 100$, but use this condition only, somewhat, on the first day of month. Then, view, which will use condition on sum only on first day of month will look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_ORDERS AS SELECT order_name FROM t_orders
WHERE (CASE WHEN EXTRACT(day from current_date) = 1 THEN (CASE WHEN (order_sum > 100) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ELSE 1 END = 1)
```

But, as i said, this is a bad practice and is horrible to maintain, you are literally copying your function, generating condition into the query. You really should consider stored procedure :)

Comment: Can you please give some clearer example for the second approach